# jQuery Dialog function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I would like to change the style JavaScript alert buttons, but I read this isn't possible . Nevertheless, the jQuery Dialog box is often mentioned as the suggested alternative.

I found the following code ([How to create jQuery Dialog in function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4879367/3158398)) which may seem interesting to integrate with my code below:

```
function createDialog(title, text) {
return $("<div class='dialog' title='" + title + "'><p>" + text + "</p></div>")
.dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
}
```

**Question**: How do I combine the function above with my code? Obviously I have multiple alerts depending on the action, for instance:

```
print "
<script language=javascript>
var rndURL = (1000*Math.random());
alert(\"Page saved.\");
window.location = \"admin.php?action=managepage&parent=".$page->parent."&rnd=\"+rndURL;
</script>
";
exit();
}
```

Another example:

```
print "
<script language=javascript>
var rndURL = (1000*Math.random());
alert(\"Style saved.\");
window.location = \"admin.php?action=managestyle&rnd=\"+rndURL;
</script>
";
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must manually change it, for example changing the BG image of the standard OK btn from the example:

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
background-image:(your url)}
```

all you need to do is to make sure your css is loaded after JQuery's UI css

as you requested the JS way:

```
function createDialog(title, text) {
return $("<div class='dialog' title='" + title + "'><p>" + text + "</p></div>")
.dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    open:function(){
        var allButtons = $("button", $(this).parent());
        //close button
        //$(allButtons[0]);

        //OK / Confirm button
        $(allButtons[1]).css("background-image",  "url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/HILLBLU_button_background.svg)");

        //Cancel button
        $(allButtons[2]).css("background-image", "url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/HILLBLU_button_background.svg)");

        //thats for you to see in the logs your buttons
        console.log(allButtons)
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Too advanced for me at first sight. If possible, I would like to use/edit the function above..

Comment: is this what you wanted?

Comment: Cheers :) So basically the pop up will appear within the background image of the used url? What would be the "print code" for my CSS stylesheet when using this function?

Comment: yes, the bgImage will be as the url. and i couldnt understand the other Q, since with this you dont need any other CSS

Comment: unfortunately i am not familiar with that edit...i dont know what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

you can use twitter bootstrap with html5 for beautiful Modal/Dialog Window as you can customize bootstrap css

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

please look below example too
http://hmelius.com/avant/ui-modals.php

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But as mentioned I'm a beginner and would like to stick to the function above, if possible..

Answer (score 1):

You can totally replace the alert and confirm dialogs in javascript.  [Alertify](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) and [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) are such frameworks.  Or you can make your own by basically doing this:

```
window.alert = function(...){
    // ... open up whatever you'd like here ...
}

window.confirm = function(...){
    // ... open up an alert with more buttons and handle the interaction ...
}
```